# {Magento} Controls & encodings

Tags: magento, character-encoding

When I change the encoding in my browser(s), the controls in the cart change accordingly when I have extended chars.
However, it is not consistent and looks very amateurish. See the attached comparison image.

How do I fix this in Magento 1.4.0.1? Or, is it a browser issue, and if so, how do I fix it?

[image: Comparison image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you create your MySQL server? When you didn't set correct collation while creating a database, you can always face of troubles. Try following :

`mysql > CREATE DATABASE sample DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI;`

UT8_UNICODE_CI has many character sets.

Comment: do you mean table or database?

Comment: Both are setup correctly: Well, I just looked and it seems the DB is latin_swedish_ci and the customer_entity_varchar table is utf8_general_ci.

Comment: please change with my code. latin_swedish and general_ci doesn't work properly!

Comment: I'm not going to CREATE my database. I know how to modify it.

Comment: ok, lets try to change `database`, `tables` collation, character set and share result in here pls.

Comment: How will altering the collation affect my current indexes? Remember, this is Magento, that hairy beast that uses the most ludicrous DB architecture I've ever seen in my 20+ yrs of DB coding.

Comment: I agree with you, extremely weird architecture, of course in my opinion.